# Curvature of the Involute

Tags: differential-geometry

I'm trying to calculate the curvature of the involute of an arbitrary, not necessarily unit speed curve, and show that it can be written in terms of the curvature, torsion, and arclength function of the original curve.  I've been trying to calculate the curvature directly, but I am getting absolutely lost in the derivatives and cross products when I try to calculate the first and second derivatives of the involute and cross them together.  Is this direct method the only way to go about this, or am I missing something?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Let's start with the involute of a curve $\alpha(t)$, non unit-speed: $$I(t) = \alpha(t) - s(t)\frac{\alpha'(t)}{||\alpha'(t)||}$$

Where $s(t)$ is the arclength function of $\alpha$: 
$$s(t) = \int_0^t ||\alpha'(u)||du=\int_0^t v_\alpha(u)du$$
We notice that $\frac{\alpha'(t)}{||\alpha'(t)||}$ is what defines the unit tangent vector $T_\alpha(t)$. Replace that, and take the derivative of the involute:
$$I'(t)=\alpha'(t)-s'(t)T_\alpha(t)-s(t)T_\alpha'(t)=-s(t)T'_\alpha(t)$$
Since the derivative of the arclength is the velocity.

Using the Frenet equations, we observe that $$I'=-sv_\alpha\kappa_\alpha N_\alpha$$
Where $N_\alpha$ is the unit normal.

Using the same Frenet equation we used to get to this result, specifically $T'=\kappa vN$, we can obtain the following equation for the involute: 
$$T_I'=\kappa_Iv_IN_I\implies||T_I'||=\kappa_Iv_I\implies\kappa_I=\frac{||T_I'||}{||I'||}$$

To find $T_I'$, we take the derivative of $T_I=\frac{I'}{||I'||}=-N_\alpha$

Thus, using the orthogonality of the $\{T,N,B\}$ frame, we find
$$T_I'=\kappa_\alpha v_\alpha T_\alpha-\tau_\alpha v_\alpha B_\alpha \implies||T_I'||=v_\alpha\sqrt{\kappa_\alpha^2+\tau_\alpha^2}$$

Finally, using the previous result, we conclude

$$\kappa_I=\frac{||T_I'||}{||I'||}=\frac{v_\alpha\sqrt{k_\alpha^2+\tau_\alpha^2}}{sv_\alpha\kappa_\alpha}$$

$$\kappa_I(t)=\frac{\sqrt{\kappa_\alpha^2(t)+\tau_\alpha^2(t)}}{s(t)\kappa_\alpha(t)}$$